# Using print as class method name in Python

Tags: python, printing, reserved

Does Python disallow using `print` (or other reserved words) in class method name?

`$ cat a.py`

```
import sys
class A:
    def print(self):
        sys.stdout.write("I'm A\n")
a = A()
a.print()
```

`$ python a.py`

```
File "a.py", line 3
  def print(self):
          ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Change `print` to other name (e.g., `aprint`) will not produce the error. It is surprising to me if there's such restriction. In C++ or other languages, this won't be a problem:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class A {
  public:
    void printf(string s)
    {
      cout << s << endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
  A a;
  a.printf("I'm A");
}
```

Comment: In C++, `printf` isn't a reserved word. Try naming a method `int`, and you'll find that C++ disallows it, but Python allows it, since it isn't a reserved word in Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The restriction is gone in Python 3, when print was changed from a statement to a function.  Indeed, you can get the new behaviour in Python 2 with a future import:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> import sys
>>> class A(object):
...     def print(self):
...         sys.stdout.write("I'm A\n")
...     
>>> a = A()
>>> a.print()
I'm A
```

As a style note, it's unusual for a python class to define a `print` method.  More pythonic is *return* a value from the `__str__` method, which customises how an instance will display when it is printed.

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __str__(self):
...         return "I'm A"
...     
>>> a = A()
>>> print(a)
I'm A
```

Answer (score 1):

**print** is a reserved word in Python 2.x, so you can't use it as an identifier. Here is a list of reserved words in Python: https://docs.python.org/2.5/ref/keywords.html.

Comment: Thanks for the info, and meanwhile, we can run this code to get the keywords of the current python version: print(keyword.kwlist)